# How can I change the taskbar icon using XIconifyWindow?

Tags: x11

I am programming in Linux and am using X11 for my desktop.  I would like to change the images of a minimized window in the task bar.

I am using Fluxbox.

I am currently using XIconifyWindow when the user clicks to minimize a window.

How can I control the little square icon in the taskbar when the user minimized it?

Thanks.

Thank you for your help.  The code I'm using to minimize looks something like this:

```
void minWin(Window window, bool yes) const
{
  if(yes)
  {
    XIconifyWindow(display, window, DefaultScreen(display));
  }else{
    XMapWindow(display, window);
  }
}
```

So how would I put in some code to set the icon depending on some property?

Like

```
if myProp == "green" set green icon
       else set red icon
```

Answer (score 1):

use [_NET_WM_ICON](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#id3076996) property of toplevel window

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The code I'm using to minimize looks something like this:

void minWin(Window window, bool yes) const
{
  if(yes)
  {
    XIconifyWindow(display, window, DefaultScreen(display));
  }else{
    XMapWindow(display, window);
  }
}

So how would I put in some code to set the icon depending on some property?
  Like if myProp == "green" set green icon
       else set red icon

Comment: XChangeProperty - example here http://lists.kde.org/?l=kwin&m=115435217715650&w=2

Comment: Not sure if lest flux box supports _NET_WM_ICON - see its EWMH support table http://old.fluxbox.org/docs/ewmh-support.html

Comment: Try other wm (Icewm, for example). If it works there - your options are either use different WM or fix Fluxbox