# Change window icon at runtime

Tags: x11

I am very new to X11 could you please help me with how to change the icon of a window? Is this possible? (I'm hoping a side affect of changing the window icon will be that the icon be reflected in the app bar and alt+tab menu)

I'm tyring to follow this topic but I'm so new I need a more full example please. I want to feed it a path to a image file I have in a folder.

[How can I change the taskbar icon using XIconifyWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634451/how-can-i-change-the-taskbar-icon-using-xiconifywindow)

http://lists.kde.org/?l=kwin&m=115435217715650&w=2

Comment: You have to change `_NET_WM_ICON` property just like the linked answer says. The best way of doing it is using a toolkit such as Qt or Gtk. Otherwise you need to read the image file, convert it to the ARGB array of `long` (this is important!) pixels, optionally scale it to various sizes like 16x16 or 256x256, and then call `XChangeProperty`. There is no standard function that would accept a path to an image file. Search for `_NET_WM_ICON example` on google for sample code.

Comment: Ah dang ok thanks man, there's no way to supply a path to file? The converting it seems tricky :P Im not sure what toolkit means, is that another function?

Comment: toolkit is another word for widget library, google `x11 toolkit`.

Comment: Thank you! Will deifnitely check it up :) btw i just saw you mentioned in your comment that no way to use path, :( i didnt see that before posting previous comment

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called [*xseticon*](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/xseticon/) that will set the icon to a given *png* file.